# Grouping daily observations from specific time intervals

Tags: r, date, intervals, lubridate

**Context**: I have a survey dataset with daily observations in a 6-7 day period each month for about a year. Observations include party choice and trust in government (Likert-scale).

**Problem**: the N is too small for observations each day, so I need to group the daily observations from each period. How?

I've tried the following (using lubridate), but that supposes each period of observations begins at the start of the week.

```
df <- df %>% 
 group_by(date_week = floor_date(date_variable, "week"))
```

Unfortunately, this is a mess as it takes all observations from Monday-Sunday and groups them together (starting Monday), but some survey periods "crosses" weeks from e.g. Thursday-Wednesday, and thus R creates two periods of observations.

I need to solve this problem and then visualize (I'm using ggplot). So the new date-variable needs to be in date style, and it would be perfect, if it could visualize from the median day in each period.

**Example of data**

```
Date           Party     N    Trust-in-gov-average
"2021-10-02"   A         25   1.5
"2021-10-02"   B         10   2.5
"2021-10-02"   C         15   3.8
"2021-10-03"   A         12   1.2
"2021-10-03"   B         53   3.2
"2021-10-03"   C         23   2.8
"2021-10-04"   A         58   1.6
"2021-10-04"   B         33   2.6
"2021-10-04"   C         44   3.0
```

Comment: Can you achieve your desired grouping if you group by month rather than week? If each survey period is exclusively in one month, that might do it.

Comment: Also, you want to make sure your `Date` column is stored with a date class rather than as character, your sample data makes it look like it's stored as character/factor. `as.Date(Date)` would fix that issue.

Comment: @Mako212 yes, I already used lubridate ymd-command to store as date. Grouping by month doesn't work me either as the periods also "cross" months, unfortunately. But think I have found a solution now..

Answer (score 0):

After many sleepless nights (in part thanks to New Years Eve) I finally found a solution to my problem. It's all about combining lubridate and dplyr.

First convert the variable to date-format.

```
df$date_string <- ymd(df$date_string)
```

Then use mutate and `%withnin%` commands to extract periods. Define the name as the date you want to define the period e.g. first day of observation.

```
    df <- df %>% 
  mutate(waves = case_when(date_string %within% interval(ymd("2020-09-13"), ymd("2020-09-19")) ~ "2020-09-13",
                           date_string %within% interval(ymd("2020-09-20"), ymd("2020-10-03")) ~ "2020-09-20",
                           date_string %within% interval(ymd("2020-10-11"), ymd("2020-10-17")) ~ "2020-10-11",
                           date_string %within% interval(ymd("2020-10-25"), ymd("2020-10-31")) ~ "2020-10-25"))
```

At last convert the new variable back to a date-variable using ymd-command again

```
 df$waves <- ymd(df$waves)
```